# Article about DTI of Autistic Brain

Tags: brain, autism

Does anyone know where do I find the article that published this image?

[image]

Appereantly it was created by a neuroscientist called Jason Cooperrider and it is the tractography of Temple Grandin's brain. But I am unable to find the full article

Comment: The only Copperrider paper I can find regarding scans of Temple Grandin's brain is [Cooperrider, J. R. (2011). Dr. Temple Grandin: a neuroimaging case study. In *Poster Presented at the International Meeting for Autism Research (IMFAR), San Diego, CA, USA*](https://collections.lib.utah.edu/dl_files/cb/99/cb991753b25ddf01fa6f780cca2c0dcacf86f5c6.pdf) but it doesn't contain the images you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the image (which also appears [here](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-research-show-regarding-thinking-styles-of-people-with-high-functioning-autism-Asperger-syndrome), [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2017/07/05/research-shows-three-distinct-thought-styles-in-people-with-autism/), and [here](https://sites.psu.edu/psych256fa17001/2017/12/15/blog-3/)) is the Walter Schneider lab at the University of Pittsburgh. They have a webpage about an episode of *60 Minutes* that featured their research (including high density fiber tracking of Temple Grandin's brain) related to Grandin's book, *The Autistic Brain*. The images can be found under FAQ #5 ("You did an HDFT map of Temple Grandin’s brain – what did you see and what did you conclude?"): http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/schneiderlab/content/60-minutes-20120716.asp.

The webpage is also available in PDF form here, where page 4 is identical to the graphic you posted: http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/schneiderlab/documents/TBI_early_draft_HDFT_FAQ_April_30_2013_Schneider_Lab_U_Pittsburgh.pdf.

(Fyi, I just found the source by searching for the caption text in Google.)

Comment: Yeah, I searched the caption text in google too. But I thought there would be a scientific journal

Comment: It's possible that they could have published the image in a journal, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. It would be unusual (though not unheard of) to identify a specific high-profile individual in a paper about a common disorder like ASD. That kind of case study is more appropriate for rare or newly described syndromes, and even in those cases it is standard to deidentify the patient.

Comment: Are there any journals or maybe books where they perform a similar study?

Comment: Yes, there are many studies about brain imaging in autism spectrum disorders. Try going to https://scholar.google.com and searching for "tractography autism" or whatever keywords you want. Perhaps one of these two reviews I see could be useful for you: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5083037/ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S175094671630143X (I believe the second one may be behind a paywall but not the first one.) Good luck!